# WPF DataGrid Dock panel grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping, dockpanel

I'm using wpf datagrid, and I'm using grouping to group my orders by number of order, and I also have a status for each order item, like : is it proceed or not, but somehow it looks messy on screen if I list each status for each item, because **if one item of each order is proceed that means all of items are also proceed**, so I'm wondering is it possible to move status next to Order number (Expander header - DockPanel) so I might get look like this:

> Order number :# 1 - Order is in progress.

---

> Order number :# 2 - Order is in progress.

---

> Order number :# 3 - Order is not in progress.

[image]

So question is:
IS IT POSSIBLE TO MOVE 'ORDER STATUS' NEXT TO Order Number part?:)

Here is my code:

```
<DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <!-- Style for groups at top level. -->
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                <Expander IsExpanded="True"  Background="Black" Opacity="0.7">
                                    <Expander.Header >
                                        <DockPanel Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Name="dockPanel" Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                                <Button Name="btnFinishOrder" Content="Finish order" Margin="0,0,55,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" Click="btnFinishOrder_Click" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                                    <Button.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Button.Template>
                                                </Button>

                                                <Button Name="btnTakeIt" Click="btnTakeIt_Click"  Content="Take it!" Margin="0,0,20,5" DockPanel.Dock="Right" FontSize="12" BorderThickness="1.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Foreground="#83D744"  Background="Transparent"  BorderBrush="#83D744" Width="130"   Height="40">
                                                    <Button.Template>
                                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                                    </Button.Template>
                                                </Button>
                                                <TextBlock FontWeight="Normal" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="20" Height="25" Foreground="#83D744" Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= Order Number:# {0}}" />
                                            </DockPanel>
                                    </Expander.Header>
                                    <Expander.Content>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander.Content>
                                </Expander>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        </GroupStyle>
    </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

**code behind:**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    CollectionViewSource collectionViewSource = new CollectionViewSource();

    public MainWindow()
    {
      try
        {


            InitializeComponent();


            this.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
            this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;

            var ordersList = OrdersController.localOrders();

            collectionViewSource.Source = ordersList;
            collectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("NumberOfOrder"));
            DataContext = collectionViewSource;

            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1000);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Expander.Header` does not get one of your view models as `DataContext`. Instead the header gets an object that inherits from `CollectionViewGroup`.  One of its properties is `Name`. That's why you can bind to `Name` in your XAML

```
<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding Path=Name,StringFormat= Order Number:# {0}}" />
```

Another property of interest is `Items`. That's the list of all view models of that group. Now it's easy to access an item's property in the header

```
 <TextBlock ... Text="{Binding Path=Items[0].MyProperty}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation but how could I make it something like Number of order :# 3 - In Process, something like I want to keep status and number of order as Text of TextBlock, acctualy I want to display two properties number of orrders + status as text of my textblock

Comment: Feel free to create and style the resulting text as you do in any other place. I would combine two `TextBlock`s in a horizontally alignent  `StackPanel` in your case (instead of the one you already have).